# $filter option for DateTime in WCF Data Services query URL

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services

WCF Data Services conveniently allow querying and filtering data via options in the URL.  For example, say I want Products with a price greater than 20:

> http://www.example.com/Service.svc/Products?$filter=Price gt 20

But how do I use the `$filter` option with a `DateTime`?  Say I want all Products that have been modified this month.

> http://www.example.com/Service.svc/Products?$filter=ModifiedDate gt '2012-05-02'

This doesn't work for me; it gives the error message

> Operator 'gt' incompatible with operand types 'System.DateTime' and 'System.String' at position 13.

I get the same with other comparison operators (ge, lt, le, eq).  What is going on?  How do I make this work?  Do I need a certain DateTime format?  What I tried above seems to be documented [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2008/01/10/filter-query-option-in-ado-net-data-services.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi try using the following syntax

```
$filter=ModifiedDate gt datetime'2012-05-02T00:00:00'
```

The other date time functions can be found in this reference for odata url conventions

URI conventions :

- [prior to 5.0](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions) (OData v2)
- [for 5.0](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions) (OData v3)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728283.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For DateTime filtering in oData feeds qualify the datetime variable with a DateTime prefix.

```
   http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Titles?$filter=DateModified eq DateTime'2012-01-31T09:45:16'
```

The above url shows how to filter the netflix odata feed based on date time.